# Elementos mal centrados

Tags: css, css3, responsive

Buenas, ¿porque me salen descentrados el mapa y el texto de abajo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto en la pantalla del ordenador **no** me pasa, **me pasa cuando el ancho de la pantalla es inferior a 1200 px (aprox)**, es decir pantalla de un iPad por ejemplo.

¿Como podría solucionar esto?

```css
h2 {
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.General {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.MisDatos {
  height: auto;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.Mapa-MisDatos {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.Datos-MisDatos {
  width: 800px;
  background-color: burlywood;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.Datos-MisDatos a {
  color: black;
  background-color: darkgray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Datos-MisDatos a:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: dimgrey;
}
```

```html
<div class="General General-MisDatos">

  <div class="MisDatos">

    <a name="Mis-Datos"></a>

    <h2>¿Nos vemos?</h2>

    <p class="Texto-MisDatos">
      A continuación tienes nuestros datos para localizarnos.
    </p>

    <div class="Estructura-MisDatos">

      <img src="Img/Mapa.PNG" class="Mapa-MisDatos" alt="Mapa localización empresa">

      <p class="Datos-MisDatos">
        C/ Archiduque Luís Salvador, Nº 27, Piso 2, Puerta B
        <br> Palma de Mallorca, Islas Baleares, España
        <br><br> Tlf: +034 698 256 527
        <br> eMail consultas: consultas@NEA.com
        <br> eMail trabajo: <a href="#Contacto"> Pincha aquí </a>
        <br><br> Horario de oficina: 10:00 - 18:00
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Para adaptar tu web a distintos dispositivos tendrías que mirar bien el tema de las [mediaqueries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Answer (score 2):

`.MisDatos` tienes `width: 75%;` por lo que por el lado izquierdo te esta cogiendo espacio, y ocupa exactamente 800px. Al ser mayor que esos 75% aparece descentrado (más a la derecha que centrado).

Ejemplo: Ancho de 2000px, con el 75% se quedan en 1500px. 800px entran en esos 1500px, por lo que **SI queda centrado.**

Ejemplo2: Ancho de 1000px, con el 75% se quedan en 750px. 800px no entra en esos 750px, por lo que **NO quedará centrado** y sobresaldrá por la derecha.

Te dejo comentado el `width:75%;` y ves como ya no ocurre hasta que llegue a los 800px.

Para controlar los dispositivos de un ancho menor que 800px necesitas utilizar media queries.

```css
h2 {
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.General {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.MisDatos {
  height: auto;
  /*width: 75%;*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.Mapa-MisDatos {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.Datos-MisDatos {
  width: 800px;
  background-color: burlywood;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.Datos-MisDatos a {
  color: black;
  background-color: darkgray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Datos-MisDatos a:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: dimgrey;
}
```

```html
<div class="General General-MisDatos">

  <div class="MisDatos">

    <a name="Mis-Datos"></a>

    <h2>¿Nos vemos?</h2>

    <p class="Texto-MisDatos">
      A continuación tienes nuestros datos para localizarnos.
    </p>

    <div class="Estructura-MisDatos">

      <img src="Img/Mapa.PNG" class="Mapa-MisDatos" alt="Mapa localización empresa">

      <p class="Datos-MisDatos">
        C/ Archiduque Luís Salvador, Nº 27, Piso 2, Puerta B
        <br> Palma de Mallorca, Islas Baleares, España
        <br><br> Tlf: +034 698 256 527
        <br> eMail consultas: consultas@NEA.com
        <br> eMail trabajo: <a href="#Contacto"> Pincha aquí </a>
        <br><br> Horario de oficina: 10:00 - 18:00
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero creo que seria que el mapa estuviera a linea con el box de los datos, para ello deberías cambiar esto:

```
.Mapa-MisDatos {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

Por

```
.Mapa-MisDatos {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 20px 0px;
}
```

En cuanto al problema general, diría que esta aquí:

```
.MisDatos {
  height: auto;
  **width: 75%;**
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.Mapa-MisDatos {
  **width: 800px;** 
  margin: 20px;
}
```

Cuando la pantalla es de menor tamaño, y el tamaño del 75% del contenedor es menor que los 800px del contenido, empieza la fiesta... Eso podria explicar porque te pasa en pantallas de menos de 1200px como dices.

Prueba esto a ver si te lo soluciona, copia estos ajustes:

```
.MisDatos {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Muy sencillo:

Añade `max-width: 100%;` a `.Datos-MisDatos` y a `.Mapa-MisDatos` se adaptará a la pantalla:

```
.Mapa-MisDatos, .Datos-MisDatos {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```